# Kotlin coroutines channel mapLatest confusion

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My aim is to have a long lived singleton (that survives fragments being destroyed and that will be used by various view models in my app).

This singleton will expose a `Channel<Boolean>`, which I want to send values to. This singleton will be responsible for doing work based on if the sent value to this channel is `true|false` (i.e. - do a job if the channel is sent a value `true` else cancel the existing job).

There will be multiple fragments that will ultimately access this singleton and send `true|false` to this channel. However, it is given that there will only be one fragment interacting with this singleton at any given time. In addition, calls to `offer` on the `Channel` will all be made from the main thread and should therefore be synchronous. I will set my `Channel` to use `Channel.BUFFERED` for the `capacity` such that "quick" calls to the `offer` function will become buffered rather than discarding the previous "offered" values.

In my solution, I am using DI and Room DB, however I have been able to reproduce my issue with some simple code without the complexity of Room/DI. This seems to be a misunderstanding of coroutines/flows on my end.

I have hit upon an issue which I cannot make sense of. The code I include in this question gives simplest verifiable example of my problem (i.e. excluding Room/DI). It is simply a fragment, a singleton and a class which references the singleton, which itself is referenced by the fragment.

See the code below, my paragraph afterwards will explain what I *think* it *should* be doing, however I observe that it is *not* doing what I expected it (which I will also explain after the code below):

```
class ProblemFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentFireBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val bar = Bar()

        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            Foo.shouldRunJob = !Foo.shouldRunJob
            bar.foo.offer(Foo.shouldRunJob)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}

object Foo {
    val channel = Channel<Boolean>()
    var shouldRunJob = false

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    init {
        channel
            .consumeAsFlow()
            .mapLatest { shouldRun ->
                if (shouldRun) {
                    while (scope.isActive) {
                        delay(1000L)
                        Log.d("Foo", "Recieved")
                    }
                }

            }.launchIn(scope)
    }
}

class Bar {
    val foo = Foo.channel
}
```

So, here is what I think this code *should* be doing conceptually:

- `Bar` class exposes `Foo` singletons `channel` property as a property of itself named `foo`
- `Foo` singleton `init` method consumes `channel` as flow and chains with `mapLatest`
- `mapLatest` should cancel inner `job` *if* a new value is "offered" to the channel
- `mapLatest` implementation will run a `while` loop *if* the value is `true` *else* will do nothing

And procedurally:

- Application fires up and fragment is created
- Fragment creates `bar` instance
- When user "clicks" the root view, toggle the singletons `shouldRunJob` state
- `offer` the singletons `shouldRunJob` to the `bar.foo` (which is the same instance as `Foo.channel`)
- `Foo` singletons `mapLatest` is invoked, with latest value (i.e. the one just "offered" from the fragment) which cause the inner job to be *cancelled*
- *if* `shouldRun` is true, begin `while` loop, delaying by 1 second, before printing "Recieved"

So, I observe a few problems with my code:

#1 If I click the root once, i.e. setting `Foo.shouldRunJob=true` and calling `bar.foo.offer(true)` then I observe that I start seeing logs like:

"23:06:44.280 Foo: Recieved"
"23:06:45.280 Foo: Recieved"
...

But, after approximately 5-6 log lines, the logs "stop" and then "resume" again after a few seconds. Almost like the flow is "blocked" by something. I expected to see consistent logs with approx 1 second between each log, indefintely. Guessing this is something to do with the downstream consumer causing "backpressure" on the flow? But the downstream consumer is simply logging to logcat so I don't really understand where the bottleneck is.

Note: As expected, if I click the root view again which toggles the `Foo.shouldRunJob=false` and invokes `bar.foo.offer(false)` this causes "inner" job (i.e. the code inside in the `mapLatest` lambda) to be cancelled. Toggling the `Foo.shouldRunJob` back to true results in the same behaviour as described in problem #1.

#2 Even more confusingly, if I trigger problem #1 and don't "cancel" the job (i.e. don't click the root view again) and then navigate away from the fragment; I continue to see the logs (which I expected - due the fact Foo is singleton), however, if I then return to the fragment (which therefore creates a new `bar` instance, and click the root again (which now toggles the `Foo.shouldRunJob` to `false` and invokes `bar.foo.offer(false)` then I observe the logs continue to print. Given that `Foo` is singleton, and therefore the `channel` property is also part of the singleton, I expect that the logs should stop printing because `mapLatest` chain call on the `channel` should cancel the inner job.

Can anyone provide some advice?

Further notes:

My *real* implementation is more complicated than this (i.e. I'm getting singleton using Dagger annotations, and using VM's etc etc) but I have been able to reproduce my issues using just the code above - i.e. Minimum Verifiable Example

Comment: 1# LogCat will suppress identical messages - do you get "chatty" in the logcat?  2# `while (scope.isActive)` once triggered will run for the entire scope of the Singleton, mapping true, false, true will mean you'll get double logging, true, false, true, false, true - triple and so on ...

Comment: @MarkKeen - oh really? Well, in my example - yes I get "chatty" as you can see I keep printing the same message "Received"... but this is first time I've heard abou this. If true, that's *awful* feature of the logcat implementation in my opinion.

Comment: If you pass the "scope" to the singleton, and it holds a reference to it, it will leak the scope, viewmodel and fragment (until that reference is changed/invalidated).  why not just have start and stop functions on the class i.e startTimer, stopTimer - using a "channel" and subscribing to it seems overkill as its only relevant to the the inernals of this singleton ..

Comment: @MarkKeen - Hmmm, so  on #2, how come mapLatest doesn't cancel inner job but *only* in the case where I leave fragment and come back? The inner job (i.e. the code inside the `mapLatest` lambda) is running in a "child" scope of the outer scope - so it should cancel when new value is emitted from upstream - and it is, if I don't leave the fragment and simply click the root *again* after tapping it the first time - I observe the logs stop. So why the difference if I leave the fragment and come back? Mem leak maybe? Something funky going on in my opinion

Comment: Your "scope" is never canceled - hence it is always active - you never call `CoroutineScope::cancel`. everytime you "map" and its `true` it kicks off another while loop.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but putting that aside, `mapLatest` is supposed to cancel the code inside it's lambda when a new value is emitted from the upstream (which btw, I observe if I stay on the fragment and click the root toggling from true->false and so on), I only notice my issue #2 when I leave the fragment and come back...

Comment: `mapLatest` code docs:

" * Returns a flow that emits elements from the original flow transformed by [transform] function.
 * When the original flow emits a new value, computation of the [transform] block for previous value is cancelled."

Comment: So, even *if* the condition for the while loop is nonsense, even if I had while(true) - this code should be "cancelled" when the upstream emits again (and it does, if I stay on the fragment - but not if I leave and come back...)

Comment: Thanks, that's cleared it up for me I think - got my solution working now by launching a new job via `scope.launch { withContext(..) { while (true) { ... } }` inside my `mapLatest` lambda and keeping a reference to the returned job, which I'm cancelling at the start of `mapLatest` lambda.

Comment: Looking  at mapLatest source - it actually does call `job::cancel` internally on each emission - this happens in `ChannelFlowTransformLatest<T, R>::flowCollect` - so you were correct it does "cancel" the child - it just handles this internally (which is handy to know!)